# How to avoid using Skip Flag in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to create a set of rules to follow for a Rewrite Condition in the htaccess file, and keeping track of the count of ReWrite Rules to follow is becoming hard.

Is there any other way to put a set of ReWrite Rules following a ReWrite Condition:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*website-name\.com
        #S = Num. of rewrite rules in the if block + 1
        RewriteRule .? - [S=13]
        #If the host is website-name.COM
        RewriteRule ^dir/page.php(.*)   /dir-subdir.php [R,L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^dir/page.php(.*)   /dir-subdir.php [R,L,NC,QSA]
```

As of now the count of rules following the rewrite condition is going above than 10, and we expect it to rise a lot more, which will make it hard to keep track of number of rules to follow. An 'end' or 'break' type of statement if available can make the process a lot easier to write and mantain. Will be glad to add any information if required.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just change the order of directives? Rather than say "skip the next X directives" move the skipped directives below this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*website-name\.com
RewriteRule .? - [L]
```

And have all the rest of the rules above it?